# Importing a project into Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2019, nuget-package-restore

I have a WinForms project with certain NuGet package dependencies that don't seem to be recognized even after using the NuGet restore option. I've received this project from a colleague and am trying to set it up so I can compile and work on it on my own machine.

Things I've tried:

1. [Uninstalling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubO0L.png)  and reinstalling Accord and OpenTK to no avail.
2. [Adding references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8soy.png) in the reference manager to everything that is giving me a warning and also listed in the reference manager (not all things issuing a warning are listed there). This resulted in additional warnings...
3. [Updating the reference path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USzIj.png) to include the bin\debug directory of my project.
4. [NuGet restore command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRibU.png) in the package manager console. I had seen this references in a previous post while searching for solutions, but I guess these commands don't work on my installation?
5. Deleting the entire project and unzipping it again and praying it just works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I moved project files from a folder inside of the solution.  Some reference file paths were still pointing to the old location and I went thgouth all the steps you did without solution.

The way I solved the issue is to manually edit (open in a text editor outside of VS2019) the paths in `.sln` and `.csproj` files.  If you see any broken or wrong paths, do a search in files (I use `grep`) on the entire project directory.

Your colleague could have had paths specific to his environment left over in the project.  I've seen this before numerous times.

Also, does your nuget console work with other projects?

[This](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/nuget-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/) or [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-powershell#use-the-nugetexe-cli-in-the-console) might help.

Comment: worth noting, the zipped project doesn't include a .sln file. I have to manually save the project after opening to get a sln file. I also can't do anything nuget related until i save and create the sln file. Im not sure if this is abnormal or even worth mentioning as im fairly inexperienced with visual studio.

i just installed visual studio on this machine and don't have another working project to test nuget functionality on. I'll look for broken paths and see if that fixes it

Comment: what happened with the .sln file?  Does your colleague have it?  You can try creating a brand new empty project, making sure it builds, and importing components from existing project.  If this is the first time you are building with this install of VS, there could be unrelated installation or path issues outside of the project.